# Adding up tables in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a table with 11 in and about 7 tables with 1 in

Each has 2 column username and clicks. The problem is that i have to add up all the clicks were `username = username` Is there anyway i can do that ?

I'm using

```
$result1233 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM urls_non_loggedin WHERE username='$_SESSION[username]'");

$num_row3s = mysql_num_rows($result1233);
```

But I want to add up all the clicks "the column name " where username = `$_SESSION[username]`

If you get what I mean ?

So there is a table with 2 columns clicks and username I want to grab all the numbers in clicks and add them up were username = usersname

Comment: your question is not clear ?) please write your table structure clearly

Comment: lost me I'm afraid.... I have a feeling we are going to need much more information. Can we see your table schema?

Comment: So there is a table with 2 columns clicks and username I want to grab all the numbers in clicks and add them up were username = usersname

Answer (score 1):

You can use the SQL [SUM](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-functions.html#function_sum) operator. Like this:

`SELECT username, SUM(clicks) As number_of_clicks FROM urls_non_loggedin WHERE username='$_SESSION[username]' GROUP BY username`

Although you should be careful from passing variables into your queries that you have not sanitized.

Comment: i just edited the questions so there is a table with 2 collums clicks and username i wanna grab all the numebrs in clicks and add them up were username = usersname

Comment: so like 
$result1233 = mysql_query("SELECT *, SUM(clicks) As number_of_clicks FROM urls_non_loggedin WHERE username='$_SESSION[username]' GROUP BY username)";

Comment: just dies..... does all the rest of my code be for it but dies on that part ( even tho there is no die on the page )

Comment: It may have succeded and something else in your code made the error, why don't you just enable debugging to see what went wrong? http://bytes.com/topic/php/answers/629295-read-first-turn-php-debugging-messages

Comment: That is very weird indeed, otherwise it is the SUM operator you should use (assuming clicks is an actual integer)

Comment: Try doing this instead `"SELECT SUM(clicks) FROM urls_non_loggedin WHERE username='".$_SESSION[username]."'"`

Comment: I don't know about mysql, but in Sql Server, you can't `select *` with a `group by` - you'd have to `select username, sum(clicks)`...

Comment: Ah yes I forgot, it is rare that I use plain SQL syntax, as I often use somekind of ORM or LINQ.